# What is the inner meaning of Saraswati following Sage Kavasa?

Tags: rishi, saraswati, aitareya-brahmana

The following is an extract from [Aitareya brahmana](https://archive.org/stream/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft_djvu.txt).

In the Eausitaki Br&htnanam (12, 3), the story of Kavasa is reported in the
following way:

> the Risis, called the "middle ones" (Gritsamada, Visvamitra,
> Vaniadeva, Atri,  Bharadvfija, Vasistha, see Asv. Grihya Sutras, 3,
> 4), hold once a sacrificial session on  the Sarasvati. Amongst them
> there sat Kavasa.
>
> These (Risis) reproached him (that  he had come
> among them) saying : " Thou art the son of a slave girl, we shall
> neither eat  nor drink with thee." Having become angry, he ran to the
> Sarasvati, and obtained her  favour by moans of this hymn (pra devatrd
> braUmane).
>
> She followed him. These Risis  then thought that he was
> guiltless. Turning to him, they said, "Risi ! adoration be to  thee,
> do us no harm ! thou art the most excellent among us, for she
> (Sarasvati) follows  thee."
>
> They made him the manager of the
> sacrifice, and thus appeased his wrath. This  is the importance of
> Kavasa, and he it was who made that hymn known.

---

What is the inner/esoteric meaning of Saraswati following Sage Kavasa?