# Who was the father of Sage Kavasa?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, varna, varnashrama, aitareya-brahmana

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37821/22253) story comes in Aitareya Brahmana

> the Risis, called the "middle ones" (Gritsamada, Visvamitra,
> Vaniadeva, Atri, Bharadvfija, Vasistha, see Asv. Grihya Sutras, 3, 4),
> hold once a sacrificial session on the Sarasvati. Amongst them there
> sat Kavasa.
>
> These (Risis) reproached him (that he had come among them) saying : "
> Thou art the son of a slave girl, we shall neither eat nor drink with
> thee." Having become angry, he ran to the Sarasvati, and obtained her
> favour by moans of this hymn (pra devatrd braUmane).
>
> She followed him. These Risis then thought that he was guiltless.
> Turning to him, they said, "Risi ! adoration be to thee, do us no harm
> ! thou art the most excellent among us, for she (Sarasvati) follows
> thee."
>
> They made him the manager of the sacrifice, and thus appeased his
> wrath. This is the importance of Kavasa, and he it was who made that
> hymn known.

---

The mother is known as a slave girl, is the Father of Sage Kavasa mentioned? Who was the father of Sage Kavasa?

Comment: [This link](https://twitter.com/anamyid/status/971317937738010625?lang=en) explains how Kavasha Rishi was a Nishada,(his father was a Brahmin).But I could not find his name.So this is a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Monier-Williams Sanskrit-English Dictionary](https://faculty.washington.edu/prem/mw/k.html), sage kavaṣa's father was Ilūsha:

> ≫ kavaṣa
> kaváṣa mf(ī́)n. opened (as the legs) AitBr
> • m. a shield L
> • (or kavaṣa ailūṣa) N. of a Ṛishi (**son of Ilūsha by a slave girl**, and author of several hymns in the tenth Maṇḍala of the Ṛig-veda
> • when the Ṛishis were performing a sacrifice on the banks of the Sarasvatī he was expelled as an impostor and as unworthy to drink of the water, being the son of a slave
> • it was only when the gods had shown him special favour that he was readmitted to their society) RV. vii, 18, 12 AitBr. ii, 19
> • N. of a Muni BhP
> • N. of the author of a Dharma-śāstra